# There is no sound in my embedded video Through WebView

Tags: android, video, iframe, webview

I have an app with a web-view inside it that shows a page from WordPress site that I have.
I use advanced iframe tag to show live stream video inside my app.
When I try to play it the video plays properly but with no sound.

This is my web-view code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.kooratweet.com/archives/category/egyptian2");
```

This is advanced iframe tag:

```
<iframe src="//ok.ru/videoembed/1048649303" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Any help please?

Comment: this might be helpful https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView